# Phone locks while using camera

Tags: settings, camera, lock-screen

I would like to prevent my phone from locking itself while I'm using the camera. I don't see any option in camera settings to prevent or delay locking. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Check the lock-screen options once.

Comment: There is no option there to change the screen timeout time specifically for the camera.